# Shopify - using custom meta fields from the Search & Discovery App in liquid code

Tags: filter, shopify, field, styling, meta-tags

I'm using the Dawn theme and I'm styling the facets within facets.liquid and component-facets.css. I want to use a grid view for one of my filter types however when I change the visual_layout_class from 'facets-layout-list' to 'facets-layout-grid' it changes all the facets into a layout grid view. I've tried all sorts to use the custom meta field.. any ideas where I'm going wrong, this is the code:

```
{% liquid
                assign total_active_values = total_active_values | plus: filter.active_values.size
              
                case filter.presentation
                  when 'swatch'
                    assign has_visual_display = true
                    assign show_more_number = 15
              
                     **if filter.metafield == 'meta_field_name'**
  
                     
                      assign visual_layout_class = 'facets-layout-grid facets-layout-grid--' | append: filter.presentation
                     else 
                      assign visual_layout_class = 'facets-layout-grid'
                     endif 
                  else
                    assign has_visual_display = false
                    assign visual_layout_class = 'facets-layout-list'
                    assign show_more_number = 10
                endcase
               %}
```

The code I need help with is **if filter.metafield == 'meta_field_name'**